# Can't connect to Neo4j server locally on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: neo4j, ubuntu-16.04

Recently I've reinstalled my VPS and have a fresh install of Neo4j on it.
I'm using putty to connect from my machine, tunneling port 7474 as I've done in the past. I'm new to Neo4j 3.2 and am getting this error when I try to connect to the server on the Neo4j browser:

> N/A: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your
>   web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j
>   Driver.

After trying a lot of different suggestions for sort of related topics I ended up allowing remote connections and discovered that when I access remotely eg. http://my_vps_ip:7474/browser/ I have no issues at all.

This is the output of neo4j status:

```
● neo4j.service - Neo4j Graph Database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-05-12 04:47:11 CEST; 2h 1min ago
 Main PID: 17040 (java)
    Tasks: 38
   Memory: 272.1M
      CPU: 1min 6.731s
   CGroup: /system.slice/neo4j.service
           └─17040 /usr/bin/java -cp /var/lib/neo4j/plugins:/etc/neo4j:/usr/share/neo4j/lib/*:/var/lib/neo4j/plugins/* -server -XX:

May 12 04:47:11 vps276997 neo4j[17040]:   import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
May 12 04:47:11 vps276997 neo4j[17040]:   data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
May 12 04:47:11 vps276997 neo4j[17040]:   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
May 12 04:47:11 vps276997 neo4j[17040]:   run:          /var/run/neo4j
May 12 04:47:11 vps276997 neo4j[17040]: Starting Neo4j.
May 12 04:47:12 vps276997 neo4j[17040]: 2017-05-12 02:47:12.417+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.2.0 ========
May 12 04:47:12 vps276997 neo4j[17040]: 2017-05-12 02:47:12.844+0000 INFO  Starting...
May 12 04:47:13 vps276997 neo4j[17040]: 2017-05-12 02:47:13.950+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
May 12 04:47:18 vps276997 neo4j[17040]: 2017-05-12 02:47:18.196+0000 INFO  Started.
May 12 04:47:20 vps276997 neo4j[17040]: 2017-05-12 02:47:20.274+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please ensure that public access to 7687 port is enabled in your
   'neo4j.conf' file. In the latest version, it should be two line in your 'neo4j.conf':

   ```
   dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
   dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687
   ```

   That is because neo4j's bolt protocol takes 7687 port.
2. Also ensure your expose 7687 in your instance to public, if you are using AWS EC2, choose protocol to be TCP because bolt is based on TCP.
3. If you are using Docker/k8s, also ensure that you expose all ports(7474,7473,7687 by default) in your containers or k8s service.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [neo4j knowledge base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/) is about this exact issue.

Quote:

> This error can be resolved by editing the file
>   $NEO4J_HOME/conf/neo4j.conf and uncommenting:
>
> ```
> # To have Bolt accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
> dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
> ```